# string replace using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a string as below.  Using sed i want to replace value detail after name: "user" and also password with "66666"
Input String:

```
        name: "user"
        value: "55555"
        username: "test"
        value: "77777"
        password : "55555"
```

Expected output:

```
        name: "user"
        value: "66666"
        username: "test"
        value: "77777"
        password : "66666"
```

I tried the below but didn't work. It's only replacing password but not value after name

```
sed -i -e 's/\(password\|name: "[^"]*"{\n}value\): "[^"]*"/\1: "66666"/' test.txt
```

Comment: "didn't work" isn't a problem description with which we can help you. What **exactly** wrong with your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/name: *"user"/{' -e ':a;' -e 'N;/password *:/!ba;' -e 's/\(value *: *\)"[^"]*/\1"66666/;s/\(password *: *\)"[^"]*/\1"66666/;}' test.txt
        name: "user"
        value: "66666"
        username: "test"
        value: "77777"
        password : "66666"
```

`sed` is a stream editor, by default it reads and dealing with each line separately.
Here I used `N` to read and append the next line, and replace the content in it.
I removed `-i` switch so you can test it on shell first, you can add it back when the results seems ok.

Comment: yes. Paswword is not replacing with the command you gave.The command i tried below only password value is replacing."sed -i -e 's/\(password\|name: "[^"]*"{\n}value\): "[^"]*"/\1: "66666"/' test.txt"

Comment: It didn't work since its only doing for value. It needs to replace password detail also

Comment: It works. But can we edit the the command I used sed -i -e 's/\(password\|name: "[^"]*"{\n}value\): "[^"]*"/\1: "66666"/' test.txt since i have many words like password to be kept

Comment: @user3755420 What's your `sed` version? Some `sed` don't support `|`, but you can try it. You can try `-E` switch too. Take time read `man sed`, that will help :)

Comment: @user3755420  I tried it, seems not a good idea, because it will replace the second `value` line.

Comment: @user3755420  FYI, I tried `sed -E '/name: *"user"/{:a;N;/password *:/!ba;s/((value|password) *: *)"[^"]*/\1"66666/g}' test.txt` with `GNU sed`, maybe it will give you some insights.